# Centre a fixed-width variable-height div horizontally so it overflows its parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

Consider this HTML:

```html
<body style="max-width: 50px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0 auto;">
<p>This is some text</p>

<div style="width: 100px; background: yellow">
<p>Some wider content</p>
</div>

<p>Some more narrow text</p>
</body>
```

I want to centre the yellow box so that it overflows the `body`. I've looked at many many answers on StackOverflow how to do this and then generally involve setting the `div` to relative positioning and wrapping it in another div, but then you always need to set the height of the wrapper div explicitly.

Is there a way to centre the div horizontally without affecting how the vertical layout works?

Also note, I do want to centre it; not just offset it by a fixed amount.

Comment: `margin-left:-50%` on Some wider content div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following settings on that div:

```
position: relative;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

That moves the div to the right by 50% of the parent's width and then moves it back left by 50% of its own width, thereby centering it horizontally.

`position: relative;` is necessary to make these settings have an effect at all.

Note that using `position: relative;` still preserves the (horizontal) space the div takes in the document flow, which would not be the case when using `position: absolute`.

```css
body {
  max-width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>This is some text</p>

  <div>
    <p>Some wider content</p>
  </div>

  <p>Some more narrow text</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox. Note that this will change the way that margins interact with children.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body style="max-width: 50px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0 auto;">
<p>This is some text</p>

<div style="width: 100px; background: yellow">
<p>Some wider content</p>
</div>

<p>Some more narrow text</p>
</body>
```